# Playframework scala, how to asynchronous convert a web service call to a response without Async

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm building a play web app that connects to Google Drive. Going through the Google OAuth 2.0 process, when a user logs in I save the access_token to Cache and I save the refresh_token (along with other user data) to database and cache. Google OAuth accessTokens only last for [1 hour](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer), and likewise the accessToken in my cache expires in an hour.

So, following, I've created an Authenticated function along the lines of [Another way to create an Authenticated action](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaActionsComposition), except that in addition to the user, I also store the accessToken.

However, the accessToken expires after an hour, and if it has expired, then I need to do a web service GET request to google with my refresh_token in order to retrieve another access_token.

I've managed to create a synchronous version that seems a bit ugly, but works. I was wondering if perhaps there's a way to re-work it to be synchronous?

```
def Authenticated[A](p: BodyParser[A])(f: AuthenticatedRequest[A] => Result) = {
  Action(p) { request =>
    val result1 = for {
      userId <- request.session.get(username)
      user <- Cache.getAs[User](s"user$userId")
      token <- Cache.getAs[String](accessTokenKey(userId))
    } yield f(AuthenticatedRequest(user, token, request))

    import scala.concurrent.duration._
    lazy val result2 = for {
      userId <- request.session.get(username)
      user <- Cache.getAs[User](s"user$userId")
      token <- persistAccessToken(Await.result(requestNewAccessToken(user.refreshToken)(userId), 10.seconds))(userId)
    } yield f(AuthenticatedRequest(user, token, request))

    result1.getOrElse(result2.getOrElse(Results.Redirect(routes.Application.index())))
  }
}
```

`requestNewAccessToken` makes a WS post request to Google, sending the refreshToken along with other stuff, and in return google sends back a new Access Token, here's the method:

```
def refreshTokenBody(refreshToken: String) = Map(
  "refresh_token" -> Seq(refreshToken),
  "client_id" -> Seq(clientId),
  "client_secret" -> Seq(clientSecret),
  "grant_type" -> Seq(tokenGrantType)
)

def requestNewAccessToken(refreshToken: String)(implicit userId: String): Future[Response] =
  WS.url(tokenUri).withHeaders(tokenHeader).post(refreshTokenBody(refreshToken))
```

It seems the only other way to convert a Future[ws.Response] to a ws.Response is to use onComplete, but that is a callback function with a return type of Unit, which doesn't seem to sit well with the example provided in the Playframework docs (above), and I don't see how I can convert the AsyncResult back to a response without redirecting it to a second router. Another possibility that I've thought of is a filter that intercepts requests, and if the accessToken in Cache has expired, to just get another one from Google and save it to the Cache before the Action method starts (that way, the accessToken will always be current).

As I said, the synchronous version works, and if that's the only way to implement this procedure, then so be it, but I was hoping there might be a way to do this asynchronously.

thank you so much!

### UPDATE FOR Play 2.2.0

`async {}` is deprecated for Play 2.2.0 and will be removed in Play 2.3. So the solution listed above will needs to be revised if you are using the current version of Play.

As a reminder, of the logic, when a user successfully logs in, an Google access_token is persisted to the Cache. The access_token only lasts for an hour, so we remove the access_token from the Cache after an hour.

So, the logic of `Authenticated` is that it checks to see there is a userId cookie in the request. Then it uses that userId to fetch the matching `User` from the cache. The `User` contains a `refresh_token` in case the current `access_token` has expired. If there is no `userId` cookie in the cache or we cannot retrieve the matching `user` from Cache, then we start a new session and redirect to the application landing page.

If the user is successfully retrieved from cache, then we try to get the `access_token` from the Cache. If it is there, then we create a `WrappedRequest` object that contains the `request`, `user`, and `access_token`. If it isn't in the Cache, then we make a web service call to Google obtain a new `access_token`, which is persisted to cache and then passed to the `WrappedRequest`

To make an asynchronous request using `Authenticated`, we simply add `.apply` (the same as for an `Action`), like so:

```
def testing123 = Authenticated.async {
  Future.successful { Ok("testing 123") }
}
```

And here is the updated trait, which works for Play 2.2.0:

```
import controllers.routes
import models.User

import play.api.cache.Cache
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Play.current
import scala.concurrent.Future

trait Authenticate extends GoogleOAuth  {

  case class AuthenticatedRequest[A](user: User, accessToken: String, request: Request[A])
    extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

  val startOver: Future[SimpleResult] = Future {
    Results.Redirect(routes.Application.index()).withNewSession
  }

  object Authenticated extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] {
    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A],
                   block: (AuthenticatedRequest[A] => Future[SimpleResult])) = {
      request.session.get(userName).map { implicit userId =>
        Cache.getAs[User](userKey).map { user =>
          Cache.getAs[String](accessTokenKey).map { accessToken =>
            block(AuthenticatedRequest(user, accessToken, request))
          }.getOrElse { // user's accessToken has expired, so do WS call to Google for another one
            requestNewAccessToken(user.token).flatMap { response =>
              persistAccessToken(response).map { accessToken =>
                block(AuthenticatedRequest(user, accessToken, request))
              }.getOrElse(startOver)
            }
          }
        }.getOrElse(startOver) // user not found in Cache
      }.getOrElse(startOver) // userName not found in session
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/ScalaAsync
you are told to use the Async method.  When you look at the signature you will see how the magic works:

```
def Async(promise : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]) : play.api.mvc.AsyncResult
```

The method returns AsyncResult, which is a subclass of Result.  That means we need to do our work of generating our normal Result within a Future.  We can then pass the future result to this method, return it in our action method, and Play will take care of the rest.

```
def Authenticated[A](p: BodyParser[A])(f: AuthenticatedRequest[A] => Result) = {
    request => {
        case class UserPair(userId: String, user: User)

        val userPair: Option[UserPair] = for {
            userId <- request.session.get(username)
            user <- Cache.getAs[User](s"user$userId")
        } yield UserPair(userId, user)

        userPair.map { pair =>
            Cache.getAs[String](accessTokenKey(pair.userId)) match {
                case Some(token) => f(AuthenticatedRequest(pair.user, token, request))
                case None => {
                    val futureResponse = requestNewAccessToken(pair.user.refreshToken)(pair.userId)
                    Async {
                        futureResponse.map {response =>
                            persistAccessToken(response)(pair.userId) match {
                                case Some(token) => f(AuthenticatedRequest(pair.user, token, request))
                                case None => Results.Redirect(routes.Application.index())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.getOrElse(Results.Redirect(routes.Application.index()))
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution works great in Play 2.1.x, but `async{}` is deprecated in Play 2.2.x. I have posted an edit to my question that shows a solution consistent with `Action.async` in Play 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Well, I present two answers, I need to give credit to @Karl because (although his answer didn't compile), he pointed me in the right direction:

Here's a version that breaks the process into chunks:

```
  def Authenticated[A](p: BodyParser[A])(f: AuthenticatedRequest[A] => Result) = {
Action(p) { request => {

  val userTuple: Option[(String, User)] =
    for {
      userId <- request.session.get(userName)
      user <- Cache.getAs[User](userKey(userId))
    } yield (userId, user)

  val result: Option[Result] =
    for {
      (userId, user) <- userTuple
      accessToken <- Cache.getAs[String](accessTokenKey(userId))
    } yield f(AuthenticatedRequest(user, accessToken, request))

  lazy val asyncResult: Option[AsyncResult] = userTuple map { tuple =>
    val futureResponse = requestNewAccessToken(tuple._2.token)(tuple._1)
    AsyncResult {
      futureResponse.map { response => persistAccessToken(response)(tuple._1).map {accessToken =>
        f(AuthenticatedRequest(tuple._2, accessToken, request))
      }.getOrElse { Results.Redirect(routes.Application.index()).withNewSession }
      }
    }
  }

  result getOrElse asyncResult.getOrElse {
    Results.Redirect(routes.Application.index()).withNewSession
  }
}
}
```

The second option is to have everything together as one big flatmap/map.

```
  def Authenticated[A](p: BodyParser[A])(f: AuthenticatedRequest[A] => Result) = {
Action(p) { request => {

  val result = request.session.get(userName).flatMap { implicit userId =>
    Cache.getAs[User](userKey).map { user =>
      Cache.getAs[String](accessTokenKey).map { accessToken =>
        f(AuthenticatedRequest(user, accessToken, request))
      }.getOrElse {
        val futureResponse: Future[ws.Response] = requestNewAccessToken(user.token)
        AsyncResult {
          futureResponse.map { response => persistAccessToken(response).map { accessToken =>
            f(AuthenticatedRequest(user, accessToken, request))
          }.getOrElse { Results.Redirect(routes.Application.index()).withNewSession}}
        }
      }
    }
  }

  result getOrElse Results.Redirect(routes.Application.index()).withNewSession
}}}
```

I have a slight preference for the second version because it allows me to use userId as an implicit. I would have preferred to not have the duplication of the redirect to index() twice, but AsyncResult won't allow that.

`persistAccessToken()` returns a `Future[Option[String]]`, so if I try to map it outside of an `AsyncResult`, it gives me an `Option[String]` (which makes sense if you look at a Future as a container), so, it has to have the `AsyncResult` added, which means that I have to provide a `getOrElse` in case `persistAccessToken` (which saves the access token to Cache and returns a copy of it for use) ... but this means that I need two redirects in the code.

If someone knows of a better way to do this, I'd love to see it.

Comment: Out of curiosity what didn't compile on mine?
Also your first option, without asynchResult declared as lazy, will be calling your webservice every time.
You do know you can declare implicits not just when mapping right? So you can just write:  "implicit val userId = userTuple._1".

Comment: Also, you cannot avoid the two redirects.  The one is in place for cases where you don't have a userid or user.  The other is if your web service call fails (which you are doing asynchronously, so it isn't in the same scope).

Comment: @Karl, actually, the changes were fairly minor, changing the beginning of the body to `Action(p) request => {` and changing `Async` to `AsyncResult` (this is a Trait, not a controller). Overall, this was a very informative post, I learned a lot, thanks for helping me!